# Need help ElasticSearch Cluster health is red

Tags: elasticsearch, cluster-computing

The ElasticSearch cluster health is showing red at all levels (indices as well as shards). We cannot afford to loose any data by experimenting on the cluster, as it's really critical.

Could anyone suggest what can we do to get the status to yellow or green (if possible)?

Here is the response that we get when checking the cluster health

```
{
   "cluster_name": "397183968343:n_cl",
   "status": "red",
   "timed_out": false,
   "number_of_nodes": 5,
   "number_of_data_nodes": 5,
   "active_primary_shards": 0,
   "active_shards": 0,
   "relocating_shards": 0,
   "initializing_shards": 0,
   "unassigned_shards": 50,
   "number_of_pending_tasks": 0
}
```

_cat/shards
Response Preview [Check this out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KwMBL.png)

Comment: can you the add the response of _cat/shards & _cat/nodes

Comment: @MayurBuragohain I've added an image to the original question. The response shows all shards to be unassigned.

Comment: This is difficult to investigate with such little information. You should check the unassigned reason using `_cat/shards?h=shard,index,state,unassigned.reason` and also go through the logs of the various nodes. This could give you some insight.

Comment: Was the cluster green before? What happened to cause it to go red?

Comment: @chani
It was green at the time we started putting the data in and then became yellow and finally red.
I tried looking out for the root cause and as per Amazon's Documentation checked for the storage and heavy processing but found nothing.
There's ample storage available and processing is happening every 3-4 hours but it's not very heavy.

Comment: @MayurBuragohain The problem is that we don't have much control as ElasticSearch is hosted on Amazon. Could you help me find out the logs on Amazon's ElasticSearch area?

Comment: @Shail Call `/_nodes?pretty`. This will return you the stats of all the nodes. You can find the path to the nodes log files among the stats.Also,did you try to do a restart of the cluster? Restart has often helped me in shard allocation issues. Depending on your elastic version, cluster restart would ideally involve disabling shard allocation, shutting down nodes, starting preferred master node followed by starting other nodes, re-enabling shard allocation in the same order as mentioned.

Comment: @MayurBuragohain I had to set up a new domain and upload the stuff all over again, since Amazon AWS is not giving us enough control to run certain queries like _cluster/settings, etc.